# WebSphere 8 input MQ node error

Tags: java, exception, ibm-mq, messagebroker

It's my first time using IBM Integration BUS and WebSphere MQ v8 so I am trying to learn all that I can.

I am doing a very simple excersise from IBM support youtube channel but I got a error message,

I have a Input MQ node that connects to my local queue LQ1 (created under WebSphere MQ Explorer) and a output node that put messages in LQ2 queue. All this working in QM1 queue manager in a local integration node (and local integration server 127.0.0.1).

When I try to send a test message to input mq node i get the following error message:

Error invoking method 'get' on com.ibm.mq.MQQueue. Wrapped exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Here you can see a screenshot:

[image: IIB 10 MQ8 problem]

Any idea of what is going on?

Thank you very much friends!

Comment: I send the test message using the Flow Exerciser in IBM Integration Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WMBv8 toolkit? If so, you are probably encountering a defect in the message flow tester. Try it a few different ways, you will probably succeed in the end.